# Match a request parameter with a JSON Object with node.js and the express framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The Code works fine with the uncomment lines.
But when i **activate the `else`** Statement i get every times the 'not found' even there is a match between `req.params.code` and `data.airports[i].code`.

```js
var express = require('express');
var data = require('./data.json');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Startseite', message: 'index.html'});
});

app.get('/de-de/code/:code', function (req, res) {
  for (var i in data.airports) {
    if (req.params.code == data.airports[i].code) {
      res.render('iata-code', data.airports[i]);
/*  } else {
      res.send('not found'); */
    };
  };
});

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('Example app is running!');
});
```

**Edit:**
I change the code to:

```js
app.get('/de-de/code/:code', function (req, res) {
  for (var i in data.airports) {
    if (req.params.code === data.airports[i].code) {
      res.status(200).render('iata-code', data.airports[i]);
  } else {
      res.status(404).send({ error: 'Something failed!' });
    };
  };
});
```

even i send the http status code 404 before the headers i get the error in my console: `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

**Edit2:**

```js
app.get('/de-de/code/:code', function (req, res) {
  for (var i in data.airports) {
    if (req.params.code === data.airports[i].code) {
      res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
      res.render('iata-code', data.airports[i]);
  } else {
      res.writeHead(404, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
      res.write('Something failed!');
      res.end();
    };
  };
});
```

**Edit3:** I set up an alternative way. But this is also not working. I am New to node.js but i still dind't find a solution.

```js
var express = require('express');
var data = require('./data.json');
var airports = data.airports;
var app = express();

function filterData (reqCode) {
  var result = {};
  for (var i in airports) {
    console.log('-----');
    console.log(i + ': ' + reqCode + ' <--> ' + airports[i].code);
    console.log('-----');
    if (airports[i].code === reqCode) {
      result = airports[i];
    } else {
      result = {};
    };
  };
  return result;
  console.log(result);
};

app.get('/de-de/:code', function (req, res, next) {
  var reqCode = req.params.code;
  if (filterData(reqCode) === {}) next('route');
  else next();
}, function (req, res, next) {
  res.write('200');
  res.end();
});

app.get('/de-de/:code', function (req, res, next) {
  res.write('404');
  res.end();
});

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('Example app is running! Cancel Server with CTRL + C');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `else` is inside the `for loop`, so whenever `req.params.code == data.airports[0].code` doesn't  return `true` (first pass), it will return `not found`, instead of going through the next candidate.

Answer (score -1):

You are sending `response` more than one that's why you are getting this issue.

> Instead of `res.send()` you should use `res.write()` to send multiple responses.

---

> `res.send()` sends entire `HTTP` response to the client includes `headers` and `content` even it `ends the response`.
>   And after that, you can't send anything.

**Note:**
After completing `loop` you can finally call the `res.send()` if it requires for you.

Comment: It is also not working. See **Edit2** in my origin Post.

Comment: `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` ;(

Comment: When i remove the `200` and `404` status code there is the error `write after end`